# Can't get my JS code working

Tags: javascript, ajax

My JS and HTML is at a JS Fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdvyx/). I've put the JSON object in the place for CSS because I don't have any css so I don't think it will cause a problem. The problem is that I can't get it working... I think I have a error somewhere in my `ajaxCall` function but I can't find it. The error message says

> GET ....[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
>   12ms]

I am trying at this on my local webserver, using Wamp.

JSON file:

```
{

"adrBook": [

  {
  "name": "Nikola Markovic",
  "email": "nikola@gmail.com",
  "location": "Serbia"
  },
  {
  "name": "Petar Nikolic",
  "email": "petar@gmail.com",
  "location": "Germany"
  }
  {
  "name": "Marko Stojanovic",
  "email": "markos@gmail.com",
  "location": "Swedish"
  },
  {
  "name": "Dusan Uzelac",
  "email": "dusanu@gmail.com",
  "location": "Holand"
  },
  {
  "name": "Petar Grujic",
  "email": "petarg@gmail.com",
  "location": "USA"
  },
  {
  "name": "Nikola Jesic",
  "email": "nikolaj@gmail.com",
  "location": "China"
  },
  {
  "name": "John Man",
  "email": "johnm@gmail.com",
  "location": "Japan"
  },
  {
  "name": "Jeniffer Gray",
  "email": "jenifferg@gmail.com",
  "location": "Bosnia"
  },
  {
  "name": "Marc Brown",
  "email": "marcb@gmail.com",
  "location": "Croatia"
  },
  {
  "name": "Nikola Ilic",
  "email": "nikolai@gmail.com",
  "location": "Macedonia"
  },
  {
  "name": "Nemanja Nikolic",
  "email": "nemanjan@gmail.com",
  "location": "Slovenia"
  },
  {
  "name": "Stefan Nikolic",
  "email": "stefann@gmail.com",
  "location": "Romania"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal code required to reproduce your error?

Comment: That's not going to work. You can't put JSON data in the CSS area. Also, can you post your contacts.json file?

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid

Comment: Why is JSON not valid? I just copied it from other JS code that was working.

Comment: As asked for by @NikolaLošić, please don't just say it isn't valid. Say why.

Comment: You can now see JSON data, i edited question.

Comment: It's a large block of data, I suggest you leave it in your JS Fiddle.

Comment: JSON in CSS area had commas after every "location", i deleted commas, but seems that was not a problem, it still doesn't work, valid JSON file is in the question. I also tried deleting cache memory.

Comment: Is there a file in the same directory as the search page, named `contacts.json`?

Comment: yes, file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within the browsers' default behavior when clicking on a `<button>` inside of a `<form>`. By default, this causes the form to be submitted, which results in a page reload. Thus, execution of your JavaScript code is halted and the XMLHttpRequest is never completed (or, maybe, even started).

You can prevent the browser from reloading the page by calling the [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.preventDefault) method of the event object:

```
search: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // everything else stays the same …
```

With this change, the rest of your code runs through, and you'll be confronted with the JSON syntax error(s) pointed out in the comments. Happy debugging! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! Error was right there, I put  event.preventDefault(); in the ajaxCall function and it needed to be in the search function. :)